# CSS Aspect ratio overriding image breakpoints?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've been trying to figure out an issue with page speed insights and my featured image on my site.

The page in question is https://streamershaven.blog/twitch/twitch-panels/

I recently added the [aspect ratio top-padding trick](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/) to my site in an effort to make the image reserve the space needed, to avoid a CLS flag. While this worked, it introduced a new issue - It is now no longer respecting the device width breakpoints, which you can see here:

```html
<img width="960" height="480" src="https://streamershaven.blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/twitch-panels-explained-960x480.jpg" data-src="https://streamershaven.blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/twitch-panels-explained-960x480.jpg" class="attachment-960x480x1 size-960x480x1 lazyloaded" alt="Twitch Panels Explained" itemprop="image" data-srcset="https://streamershaven.blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/twitch-panels-explained-960x480.jpg 960w, https://streamershaven.blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/twitch-panels-explained-300x150.jpg 300w, https://streamershaven.blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/twitch-panels-explained-768x384.jpg 768w, https://streamershaven.blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/twitch-panels-explained-150x75.jpg 150w, https://streamershaven.blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/twitch-panels-explained.jpg 1280w" sizes="(max-width: 960px) 100vw, 960px" title="Twitch Panels - an Essential Asset for all Twitch Streamers 1" srcset="https://streamershaven.blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/twitch-panels-explained-960x480.jpg 960w, https://streamershaven.blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/twitch-panels-explained-300x150.jpg 300w, https://streamershaven.blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/twitch-panels-explained-768x384.jpg 768w, https://streamershaven.blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/twitch-panels-explained-150x75.jpg 150w, https://streamershaven.blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/twitch-panels-explained.jpg 1280w">
```

The css code used to achieve the aspect ratio padding trick:

```css
.single .featured-image img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.single .featured-image {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: calc(480 / 960 * 100%);
}
```

The result of using this method has basically forced the browser to use the 960w image variant for all breakpoints, causing unnecessary kb to be downloaded for smaller screen sizes.

Removing the CSS fixes the issue - But at the cost of the CLS hit. I have tried min-height, but that isn't ideal, because that causes a larger blank space in between media breakpoints as the image is scaled down.

Is there a better way to accomplish this task of being CLS compliant as well as ensuring it swaps to the appropriate image sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
.single .featured-image {
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 50%; /*480*100/960*/
}

.single .featured-image img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

**Note:** remove width and height from img tag `https://prnt.sc/12awa8h`